# A word for the tipping level of a bottle

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the level at which a bottle needs to be filled such that if even a drop of additional liquid were in that bottle and that bottle were placed on its side on a perfectly horizontal surface with its lid removed then that additional drop of liquid will spill out.  If that additional drop were not put into the bottle then nothing would spill out?

Comment: A bottle *brimful* of water? Or *chock-full* or *brimmed with water*.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul does that not imply that it is full to the top.  What I'm on about is if the level of water in the bottle is about half way where if you tip it over on its side the water will reach right up to the tip of the bottle but not fall out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although I have no idea if there is such a term, it's likely related to the liquid's *coefficient of viscosity*. I suspect that this question is better suited to the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) site, since it seems to be asking for a term in domain-specific language.

Comment: You didn't specify that the bottle was to be placed on its side!

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks - updated!

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm really sorry for asking this here.  I will go and ask it on the Phyics site.  Thank you.

Comment: @SachinKainth Don't worry about it. It wasn't obvious.